# JayDeBe: Store a date into an AS400/DB2 (jt400 driver)

Tags: python, sql, db2, jt400

I'm trying to enter a date value into a date field of our AS400/DB2 via JayDeBe.

When I try with a literal SQL value everything works fine

```
curs.execute('''
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = date(to_date('1999-05-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    WHERE id = ?''', ('Somewhere', 5))
```

When I put the date value into a parameter

```
curs.execute('''
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = date(to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    WHERE id = ?''', ('Somewhere', '1999-05-03', 5))
```

I get the error:

```
[..]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1.prepareStatement.
: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0171] Argument 01 der Funktion TO_DATE ungültig.
[..]
```

which means '*argument 01 of function TO_DATE is invalid*'.

When I use a `datetime.date` value as Parameter

```
curs.execute('''
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = ?
    WHERE id = ?''', ('Somewhere', datetime.date.today(), 5))
```

I get the error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 290, in get_command_part
command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Has anyone succeeded in storing dates into an AS400?
Or any suggestions what I could try to do?

Regards Volker

Comment: try to use a variable string as parameter with format string like it : 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: @Esperento57 That's what I did in my second example. If you meant, I should use a bare '?' in SQL (`.., mydate = ? WHERE ...`) and the the ISO-formatted String as parameter; that leads to the error 'java.sql.SQLException: Data type mismatch. (1999-05-03)'.

Comment: what is the type of parameter in Java code?

Comment: Since I use the _JayDeBe_ driver which is a proxy for **python** to use a **java-JDBC-library** I dont know exactly to what java type my parameters are converted. A `string` should remain a `string` and hopefully a `datetime.date` shout become a `java.util.date`.

Comment: hum may be a driver problem too. Peraps can you build completely your query with concatenation before to run curs.execute ?

Comment: i think datetime.date.today() dont give a good format. Try to build a string with format 'yyyy/MM/dd'

Comment: In both assignment (`mydate = ?` and `mydate = date(to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))` resp. `mydate = date(to_date(?, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))`) I get the same errors when I use `1999-05-03` or `1999/05/03` as Parameter.

`java.sql.SQLException: Data type mismatch` for `mydate = ?`
and
`java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0171] Argument 01 der Funktion TO_DATE ungültig.` for `mydate = date(to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: dont use argument '?', try to build the query your-self with concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

After trying a little bit more I found that

```
curs.execute('''
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = date(cast(? as varchar(10)))
    WHERE id = ?''', ('Somewhere', '1999-03-05', 5))
```

or

```
curs.execute('''
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = date(cast(? as varchar(10)))
    WHERE id = ?''', ('Somewhere', datetime.date.today().isoformat(), 5))
```

that means providing an ISO-8601-string and doing a `date(cast(? as varchar(10))`, works as desired.

In case of a `timestamp` field and a `datetime.datetime` variable you should cast to `varchar(26)`.

And the other possible solution with tinkering with SQL-snippets and variables as text

```
curs.execute("""
    UPDATE mytable
    SET city = ?,
        mydate = '""" + datetime.date.today().isoformat() +
    "'\nWHERE id = ?", ('Somewhere', 5))
```

is very **bad practice**, since it leads - not in this case with a date - to possible SQL-injections and errors with single quotes in text variables and is **nearly unreadable**.